# how to remove the keys in multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have an array like this..

```
array(
   [1] => array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   [2] => array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
     'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);
```

how do i remove the key so that my array should be like this..

```
array(
    array(
       'title' => 'My title' ,
       'name' => 'My Name' ,
       'date' => 'My date'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Another title' ,
        'name' => 'Another Name' ,
        'date' => 'Another date'
    )
);
```

i tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
foreach($array as $k => $v){
    unset($k);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to "remove" the keys ? How are they bothering you ?

Comment: PHP arrays are ___always___ key/value pairs; you always have a key whether you want it or not

Comment: @malet i'm using codeigniter, i want to insert this array to my database using insert_batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)**:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

But note you can't remove the keys, it's just 0 based index.

Key always exists for an array, and must either be an integer or a string.